# Derivation of the Hessian of average empirical loss for Logistic Regression

Tags: regression, logistic, hessian

[image: The original derivation]

- How does the **y** term vanish/get cancelled ?

Shouldn't it be this instead, **h** here is the **Sigmoid function**.

[image: The proposed equation]

Comment: I am trying to understand how the **y** term vanished in the derivation. Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The expression is correct but only for logistic regression where the outcome is $+1$ or $-1$ [i.e. $y(i) = 1$ or $-1$].

If $y(i) = 1$ or $-1$, $y(i)^2$ is always one.

You can expand and simplify the $h(\theta)$ expressions to show: \begin{align}H(\theta)[-y(i)x(i)]{1-H(\theta)[-y(i)x(i)]} &= \frac1{1+\exp[-y(i)x(i)]} \cdot \frac1{1+\exp[y(i)x(i)]} \\&= \frac1{1+\exp[-x(i)]} \cdot \frac1{1+\exp[x(i)]} \end{align}

if $y(i)$ is $1$ or $-1$.

$$\frac1{1+\exp[x(i)]} \cdot \frac1{1+\exp[x(i)]}$$ is equal to the last the h(theta) expressions in the original photo, and given that $y(i)^2$ is always one, this proves your second expression is equal to the first in the special case when $y(i)$ is $1$ or $-1$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey, Thanks. I already found the answer [here](http://www.hongliangjie.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/logistic.pdf). It concurs with what you've said.